# How can I disable automatic highlighting of the current line in Geany?

Tags: highlight, geany

By default the current line is always highlighted in the Geany text editor. How can we disable this feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to menu *Tools* → *Configuration Files* → *filetypes.common*.

Find the word `current_line`, and then change that line on the third parameter to `false`:

```
current_line=0x000000;0xf0f0f0;false;
```

Comment: If changed color scheme is used then change this line in corresponding file in ~/.config/geany/colorschemes